# VBA: Open Input Box, Insert Month/Year and Return Previous Month Year

Tags: vba, function

I've been trying to configure my VBA code for awhile. This should be rather simple but for I'm having difficulties bringing all my code together.

What I would like to do is write a VBA code where I execute the code and an input box pops up, from there I would put a Month and Year into the box and what is returned is the month year preceding the inputted date.

For example, if I input 7/2020 into the input box the returned value will be 6/2020.

My code so far is below:

```
 Sub insertDateColumn()

 Dim myValue As Variant

 Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("G:G").Insert

 myValue = InputBox("Month Year")
```

The code above will insert a column and open an input box. From there I'm not entirely sure how to include the code where I will take the value from the input box and subtract one month. So far I've come up with a code that will input the previous month and year using the `DateSerial` function.

```
 Sheet2.Range("G2") = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 0)
```

`

Any suggestions, help or references would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Split` function to accomplish what you need:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim myValue As String
   Dim myDate As Variant

   myValue = InputBox("Month Year")
   myDate = Split(myValue, "/")                            'break apart user input
   myDate = DateSerial(Val(myDate(1)), Val(myDate(0)), 1)  'make it into a real date
   myDate = DateAdd("m", -1, myDate)                       'subtract a month, allowing for rolling to previous year
   myDate = Month(myDate) & "/" & Year(myDate)             'rebuild in correct format

   Sheet2.Range("G2") = myDate
   Sheet2.Range("G3") = myDate
End Sub
```

Of course it is wise to validate user input and enhance the code to handle any errors that might be encountered.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for mentioning the split function! If I want to put this data in 2 separate cell do I need to just define the cells I want under the myDate variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myValue As String
myValue = InputBox("Month Year")
 
Dim Mth, Yr As Integer
Dim a, b, Result As String

a = Left(myValue, 2)
b = Right(myValue, 4)

    If a = "01" Then
         Yr = CInt(b) - 1
         Result = "12" & "/" & Yr
    Else
          Mth = CInt(a) - 1
          Result = Mth & "/" & b
    End If
MsgBox Result
```